# Process Builder doesnt accept input through getOutputStream

Tags: java, windows, processbuilder, runas

I am trying to run a windows command using process builder. I am not sure why it exits with 1 as i feel i gave the correct input. It would be great if anyone can look at it and guide where i might be wrong?

```
   try{
          ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("runas","/noprofile","/user:alex", "cmd");
          Process p = pb.start();
          OutputStream os = p.getOutputStream();
          PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(os);
          ps.println("password");
          ps.flush();

          System.out.println(p.waitFor());
          BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
          String resultLine = in.readLine();
          while (resultLine != null) {
              System.out.println(resultLine);
             resultLine = in.readLine();
          }
      }
           catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
```

Output:

1

Enter the password for alex:

Comment: Check the error stream for the error output

Comment: To get error stream easily, redirect it to stdout with `pb.redirectErrorStream(true)`. But [it might not be possible at all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25664203/6730571)... maybe `runas` does not accept password from stdin

Comment: I tried this one too. No luck. Not sure why it returns out 1 as exit code.

Comment: Some guy [said here](https://coderanch.com/mobile/t/486550/java/Implementing-runAs-Java):  "The password is read from the raw console device, and doesn't go through stdin at all". If he's right, then you simply cannot pass the password to `runas` this way.

Comment: wow. I dont know if this is true. I need some windows command to use username and password for validation.

Comment: Wait, you mean you don't care about actually running a command? What you want is validate user credentials? And `runas` was one idea, but any method would do? [Then check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13071363/6730571)

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get the error

```
                  System.out.println(p.waitFor());
                  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
                  String resultLine = in.readLine();
                  while (resultLine != null) {
                      resultLine = in.readLine();
                      System.out.println(resultLine);    
                     }
```

Comment: I dont get anything if it run it. I just got 1 for p.waitfor()